# Upgraded Angular from 14 to 15 and get this weird NG04012 error

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I upgraded my Angular version from 14 to 15 and now am getting this weird error. Is there any way I can turn off bundling when I run `ng serve` so I can see the part of the code where the error is in the console? Or would anyone know what this relates to? I cannot find any information about this error code online.
the routing was working in angular 14 for this, but seems like there was change.
[image: Picture of Error]

I tried to put `console.log` around to see where it was coming from, but I cannot get more info about this error

Maybe its an issue with my routes file in angular 15

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'account-confirmation',
        component: AccountConfirmationComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'forgot-password',
        component: ForgotPasswordComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'reset-password',
        component: ResetPasswordComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent }
];
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your dev config, you're showing us a PROD build output. Also 4012 is `OUTLET_NOT_ACTIVATED`.

Comment: this is just the build from running ng serve to my localhost, so this is the console from my local build. ill look at my dev config

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Maybe its an issue with my routes file I posted above, will look into it thank you

Comment: could you share a repro on stackblitz ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Im sorry, I cant share the repo, but I can send you snippets of files if you know what file it could be. all the different routes are failing to load and giving that error. Or do you know a good way to debug something like this

Comment: I can share the angular.json file or the tsconfig.json

Comment: Without a narrowed down project that reproduces your issue it's going to be hard to help you !

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I seems to have figured it out. Seems like  outlet?.component?.initLoading was null and breaking it even though I had the ? after it. Once I removed it it seems to work fine. Thanks for your help